# Run SH Commands in Background

Tags: linux, sh

I have a bunch of scripts that I need to run to start up a couple Node.js scripts and Mongo, among a couple other things. I'd like to create an SH script that I could run to start ALL of these at once. The problem is, each of these will not return until they crash or I quit them... I think this would prevent the script from advancing to launch the rest of the programs I want to run.

For example:

```
node script.js
mongod
./anotherscript.sh
```

How would I get an SH script to start ALL of these, even if mongod won't return until it crashes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the amperstand. This will launch the command returning the control.

```
mongod &
```

Comment: Worked perfectly :)